# iOS - Prompt User to Update to Latest App Version

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any method or plugin available that will alert the user to upgrade an app if the version they are using is not the latest? I suppose I could ping a web service to check what the current version is and compare with the user's version and go from there. As an aside, is there a way to check the current version of the app (some property I don't know about) or do you simply have to hardcode the version as some float variable or something?

Thanks

Comment: Users have given some answers below on *how* this can be achieved, but bear in mind, if you plan to release this to the app store, it may be rejected or pulled from the store for this. While it's not a specific term in the review guidelines, I know of more than one app that was pulled and this was cited as the reason, since the App Store gives the user update notifications when the app is available for update.

Comment: @JasonCoco, are you sure apple rejected those apps due to this? what's wrong with it, for some apps it is crucial to be fully updated..

Comment: @DavidBenAri Yep, they definitely have before, but it's variable. I haven't heard of it happening recently.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice little open source library available called [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) that will accomplish this for you! It provides the ability to check for updates on startup, daily, or weekly, and it uses itunes to do the checking, so config is really minimal.

Comment: I'm installing Harpy it looks really cool. What it calls for AppID what exactly does that mean? Can I get that value from iOS?

Comment: @BeemerFan the AppID is what apple assigns you when you setup the application in iTunes connect. It's typically a short alpha-numeric string.

Comment: Thanks, got it. But I'm getting an arm64 error - has this cocoapod been updated for 64 bit architecture?

Comment: Is there an Andriod version of a similar library?

Answer (score 2):

There is update version of harpy called siren that will help you. Below is the link,
https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Comment: This is super simple 2 use, add package (SPM), `import Siren` and call `Siren.shared.wail()` in SceneDelegate or AppDelegate. That's it! It is well maintained and has last update just a few weeks earlier.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to build the update check functionality yourself. however you can get the version info from the app.

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

Bear in mind tho that just because you have an app up. and it has been released into the store. that does not mean the app is immediately available to all users via the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build such a solution yourself. There's no update-checking functionality provided by the iOS SDK.

Most apps just check a website or similar, as you've already considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the version from the info.plist with

```
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
self.applicationVersion = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
self.applicationBuild = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

And, yes just hit a web service.  Or even easier you could just put a file up on S3 and update that with your version number.